# MySQL ROUND with column for decimals not working as expected when inside CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I encountered an issue where I was not getting the expected number of decimal places output when using the `ROUND()` function within a `CONCAT()` function.

I simplified and reproduced the issue in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b47c7d/7)

Sample database creation and data entry code (from sqlfiddle):

```
CREATE TABLE `test` ( `Amount` DECIMAL(10,5) NOT NULL , `Decimals` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO test (Amount, Decimals) VALUES
(100.12345, 1),
(100.12345, 2),
(100.12345, 3);
```

Query to reproduce the problem:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(`Amount`, Decimals), ' ')  FROM test
```

All of the rows are output with 5 decimal places.

This query produces the correct results:

```
SELECT ROUND(`Amount`, Decimals) FROM test
```

I think I've found a bug? If so, is there any other workaround I can use in the meantime that will work correctly? In my real world example, I need to concatenate the meter readings rounded to the specified decimals with the text for the unit (e.g. hours, miles). My actual SQL for that part looks like this:

```
CONCAT(ROUND(`MeterInstances`.`Reading`, `Meters`.`DecimalPlaces`), ' ', `Meters`.`Units`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's really a bug. CONCAT just returns the length of the decimal part of the variable `Amount`, which is 5. (the variable is 10,5).

What you can do is use the SUBSTRING function to cut off the unnecessary decimal parts, like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ROUND(`Amount`, Decimals), 1, LENGTH(`Amount`)-5+`Decimals`), ' ') FROM test
```

Comment: That works, thanks, but I still don't understand why it behaves this way with `CONCAT(ROUND(Amount, Decimals), ' ')` when `CONCAT(ROUND(Amount, 2), ' ')` gives the expected result with only 2 decimal places!

Comment: @BenHolness Good point. It seems like a bug or at least odd behavior. When I change one of your `Decimals` values to 10. The query using `Decimals` only returns 5 decimals. But when I manually set the amount of decimals to 10 by using '10'. It returns 10 decimals. Apparently when ROUND is using a table variable it always returns the table specified amount of decimals.

Comment: Except that `ROUND(Amount, Decimals)` works as expected. It's only when it's inside a `CONCAT` that the behavior changes!

Comment: @BenHolness My MySQL version (5.7.22) shows the same odd behavior regardless of using `CONCAT`

Comment: interesting, the SQL fiddle (on 5.6) has that one "working" and the other not